# Stop java stream computations based on previous computation results

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

*How to break stream computation based on previous results? If it's obvious that stream.filter(...).count() would be less than some number - how to stop stream computation?*

I have the following code which checks if some `sampleData` passes the `predicate` test:

```
// sampleData.size() may be greater than 10.000.000
Set<String> sampleData = downloadFromWeb(); 
return sampleData.stream().filter(predicate::test).count() > sampleData.size() * coefficient;
```

I could have thousands of `sampleData`. The problem is that this code is ineffective. For example, if `coefficient` equals `0.5`, `sampleData.size() = 10_000_000`, and first `5_000_000` elements fails the `predicate::test` - there is no reason to validate last `5_000_000` elements (*count() will never be greater than `5_000_000`*).

Comment: Why not just use a for loop? Java 9 will provide an Stream::takeWhile method which should do what you need.

Comment: You want to return true after half+1 is true AND false after half+1 is false?

Comment: @ByeBye I want to return exact count if it greater than half, and zero or something else if the count is less than the half

Comment: @daniu sure, I can write for loop. Every java stream can be re-written with loops. Just wondering if it's possible with Java stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ZhekaKozlov’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46173817/2711488) is heading into the right direction, but it lacks the negation. For the matches to be larger than a certain threshold, the number of non matching elements must be smaller than “size - threshold”. If we test for the nonmatching elements to be smaller, we can apply a `limit` to stop once they become larger:

```
Set<String> sampleData = downloadFromWeb();
final long threshold = sampleData.size()-(long)(sampleData.size() * coefficient);
return sampleData.stream()
                 .filter(predicate.negate()).limit(threshold+1).count() < threshold;
```

There is, by the way, no reason to create a method reference to the test method of an existing `Predicate` like with `predicate::test`. Just pass the `Predicate` to the `filter` method. The code above also uses `predicate.negate()` instead of `predicate.negate()::test`…

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is no short circuit. E.g. if you want to test that Set.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) contains 3 elements less than 4, it will test all 10 elements, but you need only to test first 3 elements. This solution is just the opposite of mine.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov: since a `Set` has no defined order, there are no “first” three elements, but anyway, your code does short-circuit once it encountered enough matching elements, mine does short-circuit when it encountered enough non-matching elements. Both have their point, but mine is what the OP asked for…

Comment: Obviously, the OP wants short-circuiting in both directions.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov: the question only mentions short-circuiting for failed elements and especially [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46173577/stop-java-stream-computations-based-on-previous-computation-results/46181756?noredirect=1#comment79309937_46173577) saying “*I want to return exact count if it greater than* …” suggests that the actual use case does not allow short-circuiting for the matching elements.

Comment: His function returns a bool value (true/false). It cannot return the exact count.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov: the question’s code is a simplified example. The OP’s comment, I have cited and linked suggests that the actual use case is more complex and is going into the direction of using the count, if the comparison succeeds. It’s not so hard to imagine how to change that code for that…

Comment: @Holger thank you for coming and providing the answer here, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

To be honest I am not quite sure this would be correct, I hope someone will come along and review this, but here is my idea of using a custom spliterator:

```
 static class CustomSpl<T> extends AbstractSpliterator<T> {

    private Spliterator<T> source;

    private int howMany;

    private int coefficient;

    private Predicate<T> predicate;

    private T current;

    private long initialSize;

    private void setT(T t) {
        this.current = t;
    }

    public CustomSpl(Spliterator<T> source, int howMany, int coefficient, Predicate<T> predicate, long initialSize) {
        super(source.estimateSize(), source.characteristics());
        this.source = source;
        this.howMany = howMany;
        this.coefficient = coefficient;
        this.predicate = predicate;
        this.initialSize = initialSize;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        boolean hasMore = source.tryAdvance(this::setT);

        System.out.println(current);

        if (!hasMore) {
            return false;
        }

        if (predicate.test(current)) {
            ++howMany;
        }

        if (initialSize - howMany <= coefficient) {
            return false;
        }

        action.accept(current);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And for example this will produce only 4 elements, since we said to only care having a coefficient `5`:

```
Spliterator<Integer> sp = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10).stream().spliterator();

long count = StreamSupport.stream(new CustomSpl<>(sp, 0, 5, x -> x > 3, sp.getExactSizeIfKnown()), false)
            .count();
```

Also this is possible for spliterators with known size only.

Comment: `coefficient` is presumably between 0.0 and 1.0.

Comment: @JohnKugelman yes, here it is actually the `sampleData.size() * coefficient`. I couldn't think of a better name..

Comment: up!!! I think the only way is create a custom spliterator to support short-circuiting features.

Comment: after thinking, you can use a `BiPredicate` to abstract the `howMany` logic out of the Spliterator to implements a `takeWhile(Iterable, BiPredicate)`. e.g: `test(N,E)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<String> sampleData = downloadFromWeb();  
int size = (int) (sampleData.size() * coefficient);
return sampleData.stream().filter(predicate::test).limit(size + 1).count() > size;
```

Comment: I thought about this, but still, it will not cut in opposite way

Comment: `size+1` is only a good limit if all of the first `size` items fail the predicate. The limit of 5,000,000 in the question is just an example.

Comment: @ByeBye Good point, but I'm afraid that would require `takeWhile` for a concise solution