# How to terminate a stream early if count is greater than certain value in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an `Author` class. The author class contains a method called `getBooks` that returns a list of books written by the author `List<Book>`.

Now, I have a collection of authors. How do I check if the total count of books is greater than a certain int value `n`, without iterating over the whole collection?

This is what I have currently -

`return authors.stream().mapToInt(a -> a.getBooks().size()).sum() > n`

This question differs from [Stop java stream computations based on previous computation results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46173577/stop-java-stream-computations-based-on-previous-computation-results) because in this case, a threshold value cannot be calculated without iterating over the whole collection.

Comment: @Pino: I think the solutions in the linked-to question only work when a definite limit can be calculated (i.e. if each element adds at most some constant value). Since this considers the number of books by each author, the same approach isn't feasible.

Comment: @Pino No, it doesn't answer my question. The accepted answer first calculates a threshold value to short circuit the stream. However, in this case, I will have to iterate over the entire collection to get the count for the threshold.

Comment: I don't think this can be done while "playing fair" with streams, because all of the functional interface implementations are supposed to be stateless, which kind of defeats the purpose. Also parallelizing of the execution could mean that you don't abort the stream "quickly enough" to make a difference.

Comment: So the solution is just use a loop, and return early if needed?

Comment: `authors.forEach` and break that loop if > n. As has been said, streams are stateless so not good to force to stream

Comment: You could do it with `Stream::takeWhile` if you are willing to put an impure function in there. But I would consider this a hack - streams are supposed to work with pure functions that operate on the data in the stream alone. A for-loop would be more readable code.

Comment: You might try `authors.stream().flatMap(auth -> auth.getBoks().stream()).limit(n + 1).count() > n`. But I’m pretty certain that it will be more expensive than summing all the sizes as you do in the question. And in any case it’s more cryptic.

Answer (score 2):

While there is a method `takeWhile` that stops the iteration when a condition is met for the *particular* element iterated, there is, unfortunately, nothing implemented stopping the iteration when a criterion is met for the aggregated result such as `reduceWhile` or `collectWhile`.

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30740709/3764965) that you can adapt to your use-case:

1. Implement a custom `Spliterator` that stops yielding elements while a condition is met:

   ```java
   public class StoppingSpliterator<T> extends Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<T> {

       private final Spliterator<T> spliterator;
       private final Supplier<Boolean> stopCondition;

       public StoppingSpliterator(Spliterator<T> spliterator, Supplier<Boolean> stopCondition) {
           super(spliterator.estimateSize(), 0);
           this.spliterator = spliterator;
           this.stopCondition = stopCondition;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
           if (stopCondition.get()) {
               return false;
           }
           return spliterator.tryAdvance(action);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Define the limit and the accumulator:

   ```java
   final int n = 4;
   final AtomicInteger accumulator = new AtomicInteger();
   ```
3. Perform the reduction on the `Stream` wrapped in the `StoppingSpliterator`

   ```java
   final var result = StreamSupport
           .stream(new StoppingSpliterator<>(
                   authors.spliterator(), 
                   () -> accumulator.get() > n), false)
           .reduce(accumulator,
                   (i, author) -> {
                       System.out.println("Iterating: " + author.getName());
                       i.addAndGet(author.getBooks().size());
                       return i;
                   },
                   (x, y) -> null);

   // get the result
   System.out.println(result.get() > n);
   ```

Here are some test data assuming the full-args constructor `(String name, List<String> books)` and getters of the class `Author`.

```java
List<Author> authors = List.of(
    new Author("Tom", List.of("a", "b", "c")),
    new Author("Bob", List.of()),
    new Author("Sam", List.of("a")),
    new Author("Kim", List.of()),
    new Author("Tim", List.of("a", "b")),
    new Author("Pim", List.of("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")));
```

The iteration stops when the sum of books is larger than `n`: `4` in our case, so the last iterated author is `Tim` who is an author of a further book so the sum would be 5. If you remove the last 2-3 authors or empty their books, the whole list is iterated as the stopping condition is not met to the very end.

---

**Disclaimer**: I particularly dislike this solution for multiple reasons:

1. It is hard to implement, read, and debug.
2. It mutates `AtomicInteger` accumulator defined outside the `Stream`.
3. I doubt the whole thing can work in parallel.
4. You can use a for-loop with `break` or a `while` loop:

   ```java
   final Iterator<Author> iterator = authors.iterator();
   int count = 0;
   while (count <= 4 && iterator.hasNext()) {
        final Author author = iterator.next();
        System.out.println("Iterating: " + author.getName());
        count += author.getBooks().size();
   }
   ```

Comment: Wow! What an honest disclaimer!

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is not suggested to use impure functions with lambda but this specific scenario could be handled via use of threadsafe mutable objects since short circuiting the stream with accumulated result is stateful.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Supplier<Author> authorSupplier = () -> new Author(Arrays.asList(new Book(), new Book()));
        List<Author> authorList = Arrays.asList(authorSupplier.get(),authorSupplier.get(),authorSupplier.get(),authorSupplier.get());
        AtomicInteger bookCounttillNow = new AtomicInteger(0);
        int n = 2;
        authorList.stream()
                .map(author -> bookCounttillNow.addAndGet(author.getBooks().size()))
                .filter(b->bookCounttillNow.get()>n)
                .findFirst();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

`allMatch()` is a short-circuiting function, so you can use it to stop processing.

The main disadvantage is that you have to do your test twice: once to see if you should process it, and again to see whether to keep going.

And also, this solution returns a Boolean so you cannot collect the results of the stream as you normally would, but maybe it will work for you in this case.

```
 boolean result = authors.stream()
            .flatMap(author -> author.getBooks().stream())
            .mapToInt(book -> 1)
            .peek(count -> {
                if (count < n) {
                    System.out.println(count);
                }
            })
            .allMatch(count -> count < n);
```

Because you mentioned it's for java 8, I didn't suggest on using `takeWhile`, which was added to jdk9. But if you're interested, read about it as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46850795/12769096

Comment: As far as I can see, `count` will always be `1`, so if `n` is at least 2, you will get `true` no matter how many books there are?